# React Native: Create an overlay-screen with TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to make an overlay screen that seems transparent and still shows the content behind it. I have positioned the TextInput at the bottom but I'm unable to make the screen. Image is below for a better idea

I am using `react-navigation` for `header area`.

> This is my code to make TextInput at the bottom.

```
const CreateTodoScreen = props => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}
                              behavior="padding"
                              keyboardVerticalOffset={100}>

            <View style={{flex:1,width: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                <View>
                <TextInput

                    value={title}
                    onChangeText={text => setTitle(text)}
                    autoFocus={true}
                    placeholder={"e.g. call Alex"}
                    style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'black'}}
                />

                </View>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
};
```

Any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a `Modal` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html with `transparent={true}`?

Comment: @zaytrix thanks, man. I tried adding model and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible in react-native to make such transparent screen

Yes, you can use `rgba` or set the background color to `transparent`.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}> // Transparent View
    ...
</View>
```

Comment: I tried that did not work. I added `style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}` to the  `View` just below the `keyboardAvoidingView` element.

Comment: @adityakumar Maybe it gets `gray` because you are focused on the `TextInput`?

Comment: yeah I did put `autoFocus on input`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, add listeners to show TextInput and gray overlay when the keyboard is up

```
const CreateTodoScreen = props => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
      behavior="height"
      keyboardVerticalOffset={20}>


      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)', zIndex: 9 }} />
        <View style={{ zIndex: 0 }}>
          <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,242,232)' }} />
          <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} />
          <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,242,232)' }} />
          <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,242,232)' }} />
          <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,242,232)' }} />
          <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,242,232)' }} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ height: 48 }}>
        <TextInput
          value={title}
          onChangeText={text => setTitle(text)}
          autoFocus={true}
          placeholder={"e.g. call Alex"}
          style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'black' }}
        />
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
};
```

Comment: I dont have any content to show here. I am trying to make it transparent so that previous screen is partially visible.

Comment: Okay try this out

Comment: It did make the screen look greyish but not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

This is working. Please keep in mind that there is nothing else in the screen, so you are only able to see the greyish overlay. Also, remove `keyboardVerticalOffset` to make it more similar to the image.

```
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        behavior="padding">
        <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <View
            style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.5)',
              bottom: 0,
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              left: 0,
              position: 'absolute',
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              zIndex: 2,
            }}>
            <TextInput
              value={'hola'}
              onChangeText={() => {}}
              autoFocus={true}
              placeholder={'e.g. call Alex'}
              style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'black' }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Text input is already at the bottom of the screen I want to make the whole screen transparent except header and textInput field.

Comment: Well, this styling is not for position the TextInput itself. This View component shows the desired screen you are describing. I have used it to make what you are describing. Maybe we shall consider where is it placing the TextInput, but it won't be a problem.

Comment: But this styling did not make the screen transparent. I tried adding different property as well but it did not work as described in the image.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I have tried it and it does work.

Comment: It's not working in my case I don't know why. This is how it looks see here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqxmy5nsjqqvbu8/Screenshot_20190911_210343.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Ok, I am now confused. What is exactly what you want? You can make the view greyish with different opacity but you can't make it transparent at all. If it is transparent, you won't see the difference. 
You won't see anything behind because there is nothing behind. One thing I can add is to make it only visible when TextInput is focused.

Comment: okay there is an app name todoist I wanted to add functionality like that. Now I think I have to choose some other options.